# Laravel Fractal Transform - return boolean from the transformer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is it possible to return boolean if record is exist?

```
public function includeIsFavorite( Model $model ){
        $is_favorite =  $this->item( $model->favorite, new FavoriteTransformer() );
        //if $is_favorite is not empty 
        //then return true here...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with this?

Comment: I just want to ask if there is possibility to return boolean from the laravel fractal transformation instead of array data :)